# Pagination with cx_Oracle and flask_restful

Tags: python, flask-restful, cx-oracle

Am working on a REST API using flask-restful but I need to paginate my endpoint.

I have google but I only found article related to SQLAlchemy.

Comment: I can't help with flask-restful, but on the cx_Oracle side, make sure to check out the cx_Oracle doc on [Limiting Rows](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#limiting-rows) which speaks about pagination in terms of the SQL query.  Make sure you use bind variables.

Comment: Thanks Chris, your suggestion worked fine for me.I used oracle pagination and it worked fine

Comment: Thanks Chris, your suggestion worked fine for me.